# How do I review an edit suggestion adding empty tags?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, suggested-edits

For the second time in the past few minutes in the Suggested Edits review queue, I've come across posts where only the [watchconnectivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/watchconnectivity) tag was edited in. The tag has no wiki and is tagged to only 9 questions. To me, this calls for a reject:

> **irrelevant tags**
>
> This edit introduces tags that do not help to define the topic of the question. Tags should help to describe what
>   the question is about, not just what it contains.

Is this the correct action?  If so, should someone inform the suggesting editor as both edit suggestions were theirs?

Comment: From a quick glance at their activity profile, looks like that user has spent the last couple hours or so editing that tag in to every location they are able.

Comment: Looks like `WatchConnectivity` is an emerging framework for [\[providing\] a two-way communications conduit between an iOS app and a WatchKit extension on a paired Apple Watch](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WatchConnectivity/Reference/WatchConnectivity_framework/index.html)

Comment: The new tag seems a bit redundant as those questions either already have [watchkit] or [watch-os-2] tags on them. I will let those more familiar with Apple development be the judge.

Comment: I'd suspect the editor created that tag themselves. We should rollback all of these edits and delete the useless tag.

Comment: Judging from the tag's [top user's](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/watchconnectivity/topusers) I would agree with you, @πάνταῥεῖ (edit: if it weren't for @OhBeWise's) point below.. ;)

Comment: Except it requires 1500 rep to create a tag.

Comment: @OhBeWise Good catch. :)  Any way us peons can see who created a tag?

Comment: Tag is gone now.

Comment: Interestingly enough once the tag is removed, approved suggested edits which *only* added this tag are still rewarded. Also in the edit history of a question, there appears an approved edit where nothing was changed. Quirky.

Comment: Or maybe the tag should be there. There are already many tags for frameworks and even classes. More so the communication between the iPhone and the Apple Watch is a very specific thing, completely separate from UIKit or WatchKit.

Comment: @RMenke, tag is something that categorizes questions. We do not have to have too many tags, it means too many categories. Specific categories helps people to get questions quickly; however, you might not even find that specific category from garbage of those.

Comment: @totten New users abuse tags and always put in as much as possible. It really gets silly. Tagging a class and all super classes, the general framework, language, IDE, and platform makes no sense. However for the experienced SO user, having a tag like `WatchConnectivity` would be useful. They know their issue is unrelated to language or other frameworks. I believe SO should be shaped for and by those more experienced users and not be held back by new user mistakes. That is why we have the entire review process.

Comment: @RMenke I would have been fine with the tag had it actually meant something, had a wiki, etc. Perhaps there should be some automated checks or some standard to prevent empty tags from being saved/added to questions. Otherwise we have new tags created which "sound official" enough that auto-reviewers pass it off as a good edit when such a dummy-tag is added to a question.

Comment: @OhBeWise totally agree with you on that.